# How do I put Radiobuttonlist under a row on asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

[image displaying gridview with questions and answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHLpb.jpg)I'm writing an e-exam or quiz site, but I'm using Gridview to display questions and radio button list for answers.
Now my problem is, the radio button list keep appearing on the same row as the question bound field.

I want the radio buttons for options/answers to appear under the questions not on the same row with it.

I've tried hiding the bound field for questions and forwarding the text in it to labels but it's not working.
Any suggestions or solutions, please. I really appreciate.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHLpb.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9SsB.jpg this what I want
But I'm getting this [image displaying what I'm getting instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHLpb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

i actually built something very similar to this:
https://ibb.co/eGdJ6p

i didn't use gridView though, just a regular table, and placed my radio buttons on the next  tag so it's under the question  tag.

Comment: But can you page in Table?

Comment: what i did is update the value of the question label and radiolist labels based on the NEXT and PREV buttons shown on the screenshot i uploaded.  the page never really changes.